# Cobalt and MatchThem: Post Imputation analysis

Tags: r, regression, matching, propensity-score-matching, causality

I am using propensity score matching with multiple imputation via MatchThem and Cobalt to perform the balancing functions. In my discipline, in psm studies, it is customary to provide a table that has the means by treatment group (i.e., exposure and control) for each variable before matching and after matching. Cobalt does not seem to provide this type of information with imputed datasets, and frankly, I am surprised. So, to me, this means I will have to access the data and perform Rubin's Rules myself. I can access the imputed data for the matched datasets, but the issue I continue to run into is the inability to turn the results from the balance table (i.e., bal.tab) into a workable data frame. The list bal.tab provides cannot be coerced into a workable data frame. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this type of coercion? Am I missing something within MICE or MatchThem that may be able to do this? Here is the minimally viable code I am working with:

```
require(mice) 
require(MatchThem) 
require(cobalt)
require(survey)
require(marginaleffects)
require(dplyr)

#data for use-------------------------------------------------------------------
data('osteoarthritis')

#summary checking for missing values--------------------------------------------
summary(osteoarthritis)

mean(osteoarthritis$AGE)

#imputing the missing values using pmm via mice---------------------------------
imputed.datasets<-mice(osteoarthritis,m=5)

#performing the matching--------------------------------------------------------
matched.datasets<-matchthem(OSP~AGE+SEX+BMI+RAC+SMK, 
                            datasets=imputed.datasets, 
                            method='nearest', 
                            distance = 'logit', 
                            caliper = .20)


#gets the means for each dataset into a list
bal<-bal.tab(matched.datasets, which.imp=.all, disp=c("means"))
bal

#my attempt to coerce into a data frame
df <- ldply (bal, data.frame, optional = TRUE)
View(df)
```

Comment: Is it customary to provide a table of covariate mean before and after matching with multiply imputed data? If there is an obvious way to do this, please let me know and I will look into adding it to `cobalt`.

Comment: I have come across this in the sociological and criminological literatures.  I asked the question because it wasn't obvious to me either. To clarify, the means before matching are not imputed, but the means after matching are imputed.  It seems to me to get the means of the variables could it be done by using the following:  1) object <- complete(matched.datasets, action="long", all=FALSE); and 2) follow Rubin's Rules for the means.  Would this work?  Because the point estimates are not really bothered like precision estimates are with multiple imputation, would this be a possibility?

Comment: That could work and is what I usually do, but it's not clear how well that works for standard deviations, medians, or IQR, which are sometimes reported as well. None of those are amenable to pooling like means are.

Comment: 100% agree.  I do not claim to understand how the S.D.s, medians, or IQRs would work. My main focus was on the means, but I could see a potential reviewer asking for them for some reason.  Usually, the before and after matching means--as I described yesterday--with the standardized Bias or differences in a table appeases most reviewers in many situations though.  Selfishly, that is my focus--the means.  Thank you for affirming the process for the means.